# Easiest way to create a virtual LAMP machine on Windows XP?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache, virtual-machine

I need to set up a test environment on my XPSP3 machine that runs Apache, MySQL, and PHP. My original test environment was an old box that ran those three under Win2k. That box died. Running on Windows was never optimal because the ultimate hosting environment is CentOS Linux.

What is the most straightforward way to set up a virtual machine on XP these days? I don't want to spend all my time tinkering with the test environment when I could be coding.

As a follow-up question, how important is it to use the same distro on my test environment as my deployment? I don't know CentOS at all, but I'm comfortable with Fedora or Ubuntu.

Comment: In my experience, all of the differences are Windows/Linux and not Linux/Linux, meaning that CentOS should be very similar to Ubuntu or whatever. Windows is quite different, however.

Comment: On the other hand, I suggest a day or so of tinkering to get VirtualBox to run. My adventure was worth it, and now I run Windows and Ubuntu in a virtual box: http://compileyouidontevenknowyou.blogspot.com check out nov and dec

Comment: Are you aware the the L in LAMP stands for Linux? ;-)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Download free [VMWare player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/) and install one of the pre-made Open Source LAMP VMs from the [VMWare appliance marketplace](http://www.vmware.com/appliances/directory/). VMs are also available in many places other than the appliance marketplace.

Answer (score 9):

VM's are great - I love them.  But if you're in a real hurry to get started, take a look at WAMPserver for Windows:  http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Comment: I don't think this works for me. I need IIS on port 80 of my dev machine for other projects and Apache on port 80 for this one. (I still upvoted. It was a good suggestion.)

Comment: You could still add another IP address to your machine, and just bind apache to that

Comment: Yes... tomhaigh is absolutely right.  Assuming you have the ability to add multiple IP addresses.

Answer (score 8):

VMWare requires you to submit your contact information to download VMWare server.

[Sun's VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) gets the job done and you can just download the application without registration or hassles. Set it up with "Host Networking" and you'll be able to connect to the LAMP instance via SSH with its own IP address in your LAN.

[Click here to download pre-built Virtual Box images](http://sourceforge.net/projects/virtualboximage), akin to VMWare virtual appliances.

Answer (score 6):

I think the fastest and easy way is with VirtualBox and a Ubuntu Server image:

1. Get VirtualBox from http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads
2. Get the Ubuntu server image http://downloads.sourceforge.net/virtualboximage/ubuntu-8.10-server-x86.7z (LAMP server isntalled, MySQL root password is toor)
3. Extract the image somewhere
4. Install VirtualBox
5. Open VirtualBox, go to File > Virtual Media Manager
6. Click on the Add button and go to the path where you extracted the image, select it and click ok. (you've created a hard disk image)
7. Now on the main window of VB click New to create a new machine. Next
8. Set a name for it and set "Operating System -> "Other" and "Verison" -> "Other/Unknown". Next
9. Set base memory at least to 256mb. Next
10. Now select the hd image you've already created. Next
11. Finish. Now go to the newly created VM, right-click and select "Settings"
12. In the General options click the Advanced tab and select Enable PAE/NX and VT-x/AMD-V (if your CPU supports it). Click Ok
13. You can now Select and Start your VM
14. Login with **ubuntu**:reverse

Now you have a LAMP Server ;) Info here [Ubuntu Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/8.10/serverguide/C/index.html)

---

Credits to:

- VirtualBox - http://www.virtualbox.org/
- VirtualBox Images project - http://virtualbox.wordpress.com/
- Ubuntu Server http://www.ubuntu.com/products/whatisubuntu/serveredition

Answer (score 3):

Try one of these VMWare LAMP appliances or Google "vmware lamp" for more:

- http://www.rpath.org/project/lamp/
- http://canned-os.blogspot.com/2006/10/grandmas-lamp-its-easy-enough-for.html

Answer (score 2):

I was pretty sure that the CentOS site had a VM available for download the last time I went there looking for ISOs, but I can't find it now... maybe I have it confused with something else.  Regardless, acquiring CentOS ISOs is easy enough, and you can just install them into a VM.  Or, as others have said, you can check out the VM marketplace.  I think [this one](http://www.vmware.com/appliances/directory/60819) might be just what you need, but I didn't look very hard.

Answer (score 1):

www.xampp.org

thats whats up

Comment: i'll vote this up because I use xampp. Why vote it down, anyway? It is the EASIEST way, maybe not the best though.

Comment: Part of the question was "What is the most straightforward way to set up a virtual machine on XP these days?" xampp may rock, but it surely cannot be called a virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

Use a free version of [VMWare Server](http://www.vmware.com/products/server/) or their [VM Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/) with the free [LAMP stack virtual appliance](http://www.vmware.com/appliances/directory/854) (a preconfigured VM)

Answer (score 1):

Other have already pointed you towards VMware's virtual appliance store, so I'll just reply to your other question: if you are comfortable with Fedora you should cope quite well with CentOS, since both distros are RedHat-based. And for this reason I'll suggest you to use exactly the same distro you'll use in production; difference between distros usually are minimal but could bite sometimes.

bye!

Answer (score 1):

All this Wamps and Xaamps are not necessary. The best way to use LAMP on Windows is by manually installing it. This way you are in control and you will also learn a lot. It is very simple so here's my howto on this topic:

[LAMP on Windows](http://www.techytalk.info/2009/03/apache-mysql-php-server-on-windows/)

Answer (score 0):

Another BIG vote for WAMPserver for Windows: http://www.wampserver.com/en/

I tried a VM but it required too many resources on my netbook (yes netbook) and it adds the complexity of yet another OS to manage, backup and move files to and from.  Basically my time is too limited to be playing with yet another OS.

With the WAMPServer installed, I just needed to set an ALIAS to my existing project location, load my data into MySQL and I was good to go.

I really wish I would have found it eons ago.

I would have upvoted the other answer but I don't yet rate..  :)